# Clarification of terms of use in mobile apps

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to interpret the Google Maps API terms of use.  It says an app must be "freely and publicly accessible".  But there is an exception for mobile apps in section "9.1.2 Exceptions" shown below.  It's not clear to me if "for a fee" means that the app must have a non-zero price.  In my case, I have a purely mobile app that would be available in app stores for free, but the full use of the app would be limited to a select set of users.  The terms also say I can require users to log in to use it.  Is there a requirement to provide log in credential to anyone?

---

9.1.2 Exceptions.

(b) Mobile Applications.
(i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

Answer (score 0):

The ToS exception for mobile applications essentially fully excludes Android applications from both the Free Access and Public Access requirements. You do not need to to require users to log in nor do you need to provide public access to all users.

```
The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store. 

The rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is an Android application that uses the Google Maps Android API.
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I noticed that, but I need to support at least iOS as well.

Comment: @CraigP Ok, then my understanding of the terms would require you to adhere to the Public Access portion of the terms then. You would still be exempt from Free Access which specifies an application available in "in online store" but Public Access specifies Android. That said I see Public Access as an edge case where applications only exist in internal private repositories.